# Have to vs Must

Tags: difference

What's the difference between **"have to"** and **"must"**? Or can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 7):

According to [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/must-have-to-and-need), in the majority of situations, **must**, **have to** and **need to** are synonymous.

For must and have to:

- They can both be used to say that something is required by law
- They can both be used to say that something is very likely
- They can both be used to add emphasis to a statement
- They can both used to communicate a desire for something to happen, though **have to** is more commonly used this way in American English than **must**
- They can both be used in questions or statements to convey anger or irritation, though with slightly different constructions

Britannica identifies two differences between **must** and **have to**:

- **must** is somewhat more formal than **have to**
- if you have to do, finish, etc. (something) or have (something) to do, finish, etc., that means that the thing mentioned has to be done in order to complete a task.

The degree of formality is certainly important, and may be more significant than other factors in spoken English.

One important grammatical difference that the Britannica article doesn't mention is that **must** is a [defective verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb#:%7E:text=In%20linguistics%2C%20a%20defective%20verb,language%20can%20be%20conjugated%20for.) because it cannot be used in certain circumstances, for example past and future obligations. Defective verbs are normally matched by a two-word sequence (in this case **have to**), which is used when **must** won't work.

---

As can be seen by the number of downvotes flying around, this is a contentious issue.

There are many grammar books and web sites that state that **must** relates to internal obligations and **have to** relates to external obligations. These include the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/must?q=Must%20and%20have%20%28got%29%20to) and John Eastwood's [Oxford Guide to English Grammar](https://www.uop.edu.jo/download/research/members/oxford_guide_to_english_grammar.pdf), section 93. On the other hand, we have the Britannia article I summarized above, and this [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446403/deontic-must-have-to-and-had-to) answer.

It is possible that there may be some underlying preference, but  when you look at actual NGrams, no clear pattern emerges: possibly because other factors (for example, spoken/written, formal/informal) have a stronger effect.

- for: This [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=simply%20have%20to%20meet%2Csimply%20must%20meet&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) shows that, for a desire for something to happen, "simply must meet" is much more common than "simply have to meet".
- against: this [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20to%20wash%20my%20hair%2Cmust%20wash%20my%20hair&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20to%20wash%20my%20hair%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmust%20wash%20my%20hair%3B%2Cc0) shows that the internal obligation "have to wash my hair" is very much more common than "must wash my hair"
- against: this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=governments%20must%2C%20governments%20have%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgovernments%20must%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgovernments%20have%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgovernments%20must%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgovernments%20have%20to%3B%2Cc0) describes an extrernal obligation, but shows that "Governments must" is roughly three times as widely used as "governments have to"

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446403/deontic-must-have-to-and-had-to In practice there is no difference in meaning between  "must" and "have to". Neither one is more "external" than the other. The real differences are others.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks for that. my I add it to my answer?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: I have counteracted one downvote for this excellent answer.